# default state gets changed inside reducer without anything acting up on it

Tags: javascript, redux, reducers

In one of my reducer files I initially set my default state to look like this:

```
export let defaultState = {
    devices: {},
    canBeDeleted: false,
    willBeDeleted: null,

};
```

When I checked the state inside my mapStateToProps function, I noticed that state now looks like this:

```
device:
       canBeDeleted: true
devices: {XXXXXXXXXX: {…}, XXXXXXXXX: {…}}
willBeDeleted: null
```

When I add additional parameters to device, they appear. However, when I delete them, they remain.  What is causing default state to change canBeDeleted, from false to true?  Also, what is causing the additional parameters to remain even after I've deleted from my code?

mapStateToProps looks like this

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log('mapStateToProps: state', state);
    return {
        devices: state.device.devices,
        canBeDeleted: state.device.canBeDeleted
    }
}
```

edit:

here is the configureStore:

```
export default function configureStore(preloadedState) {
    console.log('inside ConfigureStore: preloadedState: ', preloadedState);
    // DEBUG
    if (__DEV__) {
        return createStore(
            rootReducer,
            preloadedState,
            applyMiddleware(
                thunkMiddleware,
                // loggerMiddleware
            )
        )
    }
    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        preloadedState,
        applyMiddleware(
            thunkMiddleware
            // loggerMiddleware
        )
    )
}
```

preloadedState came back as undefined in the debugger

the complete reducers file looks like this:

```
import { REHYDRATE } from 'redux-persist/constants'
import _ from 'lodash';
import {
    ADD_DEVICE,
    SYNC_DEVICE,
    DELETE_ALL_DEVICES,
    DELETE_THIS_DEVICE,
    CAN_BE_DELETED,
    HIGHLIGHT_DELETE_ICON,
} from '../actions/device';

// device:Object
// device.macAddress
// device.name
// device.createdAt
// device.updatedAt

export let defaultState = {
    devices: {},
    canBeDeleted: false,
    willBeDeleted: null,

};

export default function (state = defaultState, action) {
    if (action.type === REHYDRATE) {
        let incoming = action.payload.device;
        if (incoming) {
            return {
                ...state,
                ...incoming
            }
        }
        return {
            ...state
        }
    }

    if (action.type === ADD_DEVICE) {
        let device = action.device;
        if (!device || !device.macAddress) {
            return state;
        }
        device.createdAt = new Date();
        device.updatedAt = new Date();
        let devices = _.cloneDeep(state.devices);
        devices[device.macAddress] = device;
        return {
            ...state,
            devices
        }
    }
    if (action.type === SYNC_DEVICE) {
        if (!action.macAddress) {
            return state;
        }
        let devices = state.devices;
        let targetDevice = devices[action.macAddress];
        if (!targetDevice) {
            return state;
        }
        targetDevice.updatedAt = new Date();
        devices[targetDevice.macAddress] = targetDevice;
        return {
            ...state,
            devices
        }
    }
    if (action.type === DELETE_ALL_DEVICES) {
        return {
            ...state,
            devices: {}
        }
    }
    if (action.type === HIGHLIGHT_DELETE_ICON) {
        return {
            ...state,
            canBeDeleted: !state.canBeDeleted
        }
    }
    if (action.type === CAN_BE_DELETED) {
        console.log('reducers/devices.js CANBEDELETED: action and then state', action.deviceItem.props.device.name, state);
        return [
            ...state, {
                canBeDeleted: 'something'
            }
        ]





    }
    if (action.type === DELETE_THIS_DEVICE) {
        // console.log('reducer/device action.type DELETE_THIS_DEVICE', state);
        var listOfDevice = state.devices;
        // console.log('reducer/device action.type delete this device', action);
        // var newObject = listOfDevice.filter(olive => olive.name != action.deviceName)
        // console.log('reducer/device action.type delete this device newObject', newObject);

        function filterByName(obj, stringValue) {
            // console.log('filterByName: new key for object', Object.keys(listOfDevice))
            return Object.keys(obj).reduce((resultObj, key) => {
                const obj = listOfDevice[key]
                // console.log('filterByName: obj', obj);
                if (obj.name !== stringValue) {
                    console.log('here is your resultobj ', resultObj)
                    resultObj[key] = { ...obj }
                }
                return resultObj
            }, {})
        }

        const newObj = filterByName(listOfDevice, action.deviceName);
        // console.log(newObj);

        return {
            ...state,
            devices: newObj,
        }
    }
    return state;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't help but feel that there might be a missing piece of code that is changing your state. If you could post a CodePen sample of your code, maybe it could be of help to debug your issue. Another thing to look out for is whether you are using any persisted state (e.g `localStorage values` ) in your `createStore`

Comment: Here's a codepen that contains the whole reducers file https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xyNGro

Comment: Erm... Your codepen has errors. You may want to check what hydrate does. I'm suspecting it to change your state

Comment: redux-persist is getting the previous state of the device and loading it.  That explains why I keep seeing those other parameters.  Now I just need to figure out how make sure that the canBeDeleted from the default state is loaded, but devices is rehydrated